# How to draw curly braces on minted and tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

I have the code below to generate minted code inside box (credit:[Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459750/104073)). That format (code inside box) is heavely needed in my previous report paper.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[newfloat,chapter]{minted}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Tabel Kode}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,minted,skins,breakable}
\newtcblisting{ignasicblock}[1][]{%
  breakable,
  colback=white,
  colframe=black,
  colbacktitle=white,
  sharp corners,
  enhanced,
  listing engine=minted,
  listing only,
  left=10mm,
  title=Source Code,
  halign title=center,
  overlay={\draw[line width=.5mm] ([xshift=8mm]frame.south west)
    -- ([xshift=8mm]frame.north west);
    \node[right] at (title.west) {No};},
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=Python,
  minted options={%
    linenos=true,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    numbersep=6mm,
    texcl=true,
    breaklines=true,
    autogobble=true},
  coltitle=black,
  #1
}

\definecolor{codebg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\footnotesize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
  \captionof{listing}{\emph{Pseudocode function} fizzbuzz}
  \label{pc:construct-ed}
\begin{ignasicblock}[title=fizzbuzz,minted language=text]
program fizzbuzz
  Do i = 1 to 100
    set print_number to true
    If i is divisible by 3
      print "Fizz"
      set print_number to false
    If i is divisible by 5
      print "Buzz"
      set print_number to false
    If print_number, print i
    print a newline
    end do
\end{ignasicblock}
\end{code}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
%%% End:
```

The code above will generate:

[image]

Now I need to give a mark like figure1 or figure2. The mark will be a curly braces that stretch from line X until line Y.

So we can define:

- starting line:x
- end line:y
- number:z
- (if possible) we can dynamically change the mark, for just one line, we can use line instead of curly braces e.g in figure2

Figure1:

[image]

Figure2:

[image]

I heavily need this format for my current report. Thanks a ton in advance for the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add some `underlay` code which allows to draw something on the `tcolorbox`.

I added some macros `\drawbrace` and `\drawline` which are adapted to the dimensions of your box.

- `\drawbrace[options]{xshift}{first line}{last line}{Text}`
- `\drawline[options]{xshift west}{xshift east}{line}{Text}`

For your example, we need:

```
\drawbrace{7.5cm}{0}{4}{1}
\drawbrace{8cm}{4}{11}{2}
\drawline{4cm}{8.5cm}{12}{3}
```

[image]

The full code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[newfloat,chapter]{minted}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Tabel Kode}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,minted,skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newtcblisting{ignasicblock}[1][]{%
  breakable,
  colback=white,
  colframe=black,
  colbacktitle=white,
  sharp corners,
  enhanced,
  listing engine=minted,
  listing only,
  left=10mm,
  title=Source Code,
  halign title=center,
  overlay={\draw[line width=.5mm] ([xshift=8mm]frame.south west)
    -- ([xshift=8mm]frame.north west);
    \node[right] at (title.west) {No};
    },
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=Python,
  minted options={%
    linenos=true,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    numbersep=6mm,
    texcl=true,
    breaklines=true,
    autogobble=true},
  coltitle=black,
  #1
}

\newcommand{\drawbrace}[5][]{%
  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt},blue!75!black,line width=1pt]
    ([xshift=#2,yshift=-3.3mm-#3*12pt]interior.north west)
    -- ([xshift=#2,yshift=-2.7mm-#4*12pt]interior.north west)
    node [align=center,right=10pt,midway,circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!5,text=black,
      font=\sffamily\small,#1] {#5};
}

\newcommand{\drawline}[5][]{%
  \draw [blue!75!black,line width=1pt]
    ([xshift=#2,yshift=-3mm+6pt-#4*12pt]interior.north west)
    -- ([xshift=#3,yshift=-3mm+6pt-#4*12pt]interior.north west)
    node [align=center,right=5pt,circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!5,text=black,
      font=\sffamily\small,#1] {#5};
}

\definecolor{codebg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\footnotesize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
  \captionof{listing}{\emph{Pseudocode function} fizzbuzz}
  \label{pc:construct-ed}
\begin{ignasicblock}[title=fizzbuzz,minted language=text,
  underlay={
    \drawbrace{7.5cm}{0}{4}{1}
    \drawbrace{8cm}{4}{11}{2}
    \drawline{4cm}{8.5cm}{12}{3}
  }]
program fizzbuzz
  Do i = 1 to 100
    set print_number to true
    If i is divisible by 3
      print "Fizz"
      set print_number to false
    If i is divisible by 5
      print "Buzz"
      set print_number to false
    If print_number, print i
    print a newline
    end do
\end{ignasicblock}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

If you inspect `\drawbrace`

```
\newcommand{\drawbrace}[5][]{%
  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt},blue!75!black,line width=1pt]
    ([xshift=#2,yshift=-3.3mm-#3*12pt]interior.north west)
    -- ([xshift=#2,yshift=-2.7mm-#4*12pt]interior.north west)
    node [align=center,right=10pt,midway,circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!5,text=black,
      font=\sffamily\small,#1] {#5};
}
```

you see that all positions are computed relative to `interior.north west`.

This method may/will fail for breakable boxes!

Comment: The great part is I can adjust the horizontal position (and the
length of line) of the line/braces. I can't imagine this. Great thanks
for the help. By tomorrow I can submit my report. Once again, thank
you. May your kindness be replied.