# Annotate with Call-Outs on tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, pstricks, minted

I'd like to do call-outs on a `tcolorbox` like the ones in this diagram from the `longfbox` documentation's [Breakable Content Section](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/longfbox/longfbox.html#sec-breakable).

I've got my whole document using `tcolorbox` and `pstricks` but can't figure out how to make them work together.  I think I need to imbed `pstricks` nodes inside the boxes somehow, but they are `verbatim`-style boxes so I'm at a loss.  (Listings using the `minted` package inside the `tcolorbox`es.)

I did find [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593230/annotate-listing-with-overlays) that might help, but it is using `Tikz` and I'd rather stick with `pstricks` as I'm more familiar and comfortable with it.  Can I embed `pstricks` in an overlay somehow as well?  Would this help me pinpoint parts of a line of code within the main listing box?

Similarly [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489732/how-to-draw-curly-braces-on-minted-and-tcolorbox) holds promise, but is using `Tikz` and won't work with `breakable` boxes which all of mine are.  This one pinpoints whole lines by line number, but I need parts of a line to show associativity of operations within the statement.

Details:  I usually use underbracing on the board to draw this, but am producing some notes for public consumption and would like it to look similarly in the PDF.

Here's a MWE for a line and the idea I'm after but can't get to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings,xparse,raster}

                   % tcb  minted
\NewTCBListing{Cpp}{ O{} !O{} }{%
                       listing engine=minted,
                       listing only,
                       minted language=cpp,
                       minted options={style=default,
                                       autogobble,
                                       %showspaces,
                                       tabsize=4,
                                       #2},
                       skin=standard,
                       breakable,
                       #1}

\newmintinline[CppInline]{cpp}{autogobble,tabsize=4,style=default}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\leavevmode\CppInline`#1`}

\begin{document}

    Here's a line of code, for instance:

\begin{Cpp}[]
    cin >> r1 >> r2 >> r3;
\end{Cpp}

    I'd like underbraces below \code{cin >> r1} with a label saying
    \code{cin}.  And likewise another underbrace below that \code{cin} over to
    the \code{r2}.  Finally one connecting that 2$^{\textrm{}nd}$ brace's
    \code{cin} to the \code{r3}.

\end{document}
```

It needs `pygmentize` installed with `python` and the `-shell-escape` command-line argument to the `latex` command.

Here is the result:

[image: Sample Output]

Any thoughts welcome!

Comment: *Please* add an example of what you want --- even a code that fails but that we can copy and compile.  Otherwise, it is almost impossible to solve your problem...

Comment: I've added an MWE and pic.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe something with `tikzmark`? Like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657375/how-to-use-listing-tikz-and-tikzmark-packages-together-to-annotate-source-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with some tricky code you can create two invisible nodes. Run with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings,xparse,raster}

% tcb  minted
\NewTCBListing{Cpp}{ O{} !O{} }{%
    listing engine=minted,
    listing only,
    minted language=cpp,
    minted options={style=default,
        autogobble,
        %showspaces,
        tabsize=4,
        #2},
    skin=standard,
    breakable,
    #1}

\newmintinline[CppInline]{cpp}{autogobble,tabsize=4,style=default}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\leavevmode\CppInline`#1`}

\begin{document}
    
    Here's a line of code, for instance:
    

\begin{Cpp}[]
        cin >> r1 >> r2 >> r3;
\end{Cpp}

\vspace{-5.5ex}
{\ttfamily\rnode{A}{\hphantom{cin}}\hphantom{ >> }\rnode{B}{\hphantom{r1}}}
\psbrace[linecolor=red,ref=lC,rot=90](A)(B){Text}
    
\vspace{10mm}
    I'd like underbraces below \code{cin >> r1} with a label saying
    \code{cin}.  And likewise another underbrace below that \code{cin} over to
    the \code{r2}.  Finally one connecting that 2$^{\textrm{}nd}$ brace's
    \code{cin} to the \code{r3}.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up with something much like this.  I didn't think to make `hphantom` text nodes over the top, though.  Thanks for that idea!  I was just shifting arbitrary coordinates in a `pspicture` for some time trying to make it line up.